# Swift - Expand tableview without Storyboard segue

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a similar tableview like the one below:

https://github.com/justinmfischer/SwiftyExpandingCells

I already have a complete tableview with contents, including a filtering system. The current problem is that I want to implement the same functionality to expand cells and show detailed information, **without using storyboard**.

The sample code (link) uses a storyboard segue, but I want to get rid of that so that it can basically do the same thing through code. I removed the label for the background. Just want to get the title and a new controller first by clicking a tableview cell.

**DetailViewController**

```
class DetailVC: UIViewController {

var brand: Brand?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setup()
}

func setup() {
    self.view.frame.origin.y = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height

    if let brand = self.brand {
        self.title = brand.name
    }
}
}
```

**This part needs to change**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedCellFrame = tableView.convertRect(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.frame, toView: tableView.superview)
    self.selectedBrand = BrandManager.sharedInstance.brands[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(.DetailVC , sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    switch segueIdentifierForSegue(segue) {
        case .DetailVC:
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC
                vc.brand = self.selectedBrand

            self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the linked GitHub code is your answer itself.

Comment: But the linked code is using a storyboard segue (see code in question). My question is how to change this to a non storyboard segue version :-)

Comment: Without storyboard or without segue only ?

Comment: Without the storyboard. I do everything in code, but I want to implement the same functionality (clicking a tableview row and expanding it from top to bottom).

Comment: The code in my answer is part of the github project, but it uses a storyboard segue I can't use due to a 0% storyboard project. 

I just want to push a view controller to the foreground when a table row is selected (see picture). I have been trying for hours now :-(

https://github.com/justinmfischer/SwiftyExpandingCells/blob/master/Screenshot.gif

Comment: try the way as described in [this tutorial](http://mathewsanders.com/interactive-transitions-in-swift/), you might need to change a bit in the source code to make it non-navigation related

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.selectedCellFrame = tableView.convertRect(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.frame, toView: tableView.superview)
        self.selectedBrand =  BrandManager.sharedInstance.brands[indexPath.row]

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailVc") as! DetailVC
        vc.brand = self.selectedBrand
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
     }//// add the storyboardID for the detailsVc as "DetailVc"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but isn't it linked to storyboard right now? I don't touch storyboard in any kind of way :-)